# Options for having same tables in 2 different data bases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, master-slave-replication

I need to know what options I have for my next problem:

I have 2 databases (sql server 2012)

- first for an ERP
- second for an website

For the website's database, I want to use a table (customer) which is created in ERP database.

I need a copy in real time of that table, in website's database. When a customer is entered by erp, it should appear in website too. Vice-versa is not necessary

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens when data is changed in the website "and" the ERP? Which one should prevail?

Comment: Why is vice versa not necessary - because customers are not entered via the website, or because some other existing mechanism adds customers entered vias the website into the ERP?

Comment: Yes, because customers are not entered by website, just by ERP. I need a mirror of that ERP.customer table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication).

It allows you to replicate specific objects from one database to another.

Comment: It can affect the speed of ERP database ??

Comment: @IonutP. I can't answer that. I know nothing about your hardware, transaction throughput, etc. I'd generally say no, but you'd have to test it out.

Comment: For just one table on the same server you shouldn't have any performance issues.